# How to get and set Spring's Autowired object?

Tags: spring

I am implementing JSF + Spring integrated web app, I have several service classes like below:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AccountService
{
    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    public AccountRepository getRepository()
    {                   
        return accountRepository;
    }

    public Account insertOrUpdate(Account entity) 
    {
        return accountRepository.save(entity);
    }

    public Account findOne(Account entiti)
    {
        return accountRepository.findOne(entiti.getId());
    }
    //some other methods
}
```

I wanted to implement a base class which contains common methods for all service classes like below:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class BaseService
{
    JpaRepository repository;

    public void setRepository(JpaRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public BaseEntity insertOrUpdate(BaseEntity entity)
    {
        return (BaseEntity) repository.save(entity);
    }

    public BaseEntity findOne(BaseEntity entity)
    {
        return (BaseEntity) repository.findOne(entity.getId());
    }
}
```

But the problem here is how to autowired the repository dynamically? I have tried to set the repository from subclass like below but doesn't works. it will cause `NullPointerException` when I use the `repository` object in super class. Any recommendation on how to achieve this?

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AccountService extends BaseService
{
    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    public AccountService()
    {
        super.setRepository(accountRepository);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be resolved by creating a generic base service class as below:
**BaseService.java**, an interface of your service method.

```
public interface BaseService<T extends BaseEntity, ID extends Serializable, R extends JpaRepository>
{
    public T insertOrUpdate(T entity);

    public Iterable<T> insertOrUpdate(Iterable<T> entities);

    public T findOne(ID id);

    public List<T> findAll();

    //.........
}
```

**BaseServiceImpl**, a class which implements the `BaseService` interface

```
@Transactional
public abstract class BaseServiceImpl<T extends BaseEntity, ID extends Serializable, R extends JpaRepository<T, ID>> implements BaseService<T, ID, R>
{
    protected R repository;

    protected BaseServiceImpl(R repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public T insertOrUpdate(T entity)
    {
        return repository.save(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<T> insertOrUpdate(Iterable<T> entities)
    {
        return repository.save(entities);
    }
    //.........
}
```

**AccountService.java**, finally, your service class which extends the `BaseServiceImpl`

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AccountService extends BaseServiceImpl<Account, Integer, AccountRepository> //implements BaseService<Account, Integer, AccountRepository>
{
    @Autowired
    public AccountService(AccountRepository repository) {
        super(repository);
    }

    public AccountRepository getRepository()
    {
        return super.repository;
    }

    //create your own service method here
}
```

Finally, sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to `get and set autowired object` and use `@Autowired` annotation then you need to use annotation on classes link `@Service`, `@RestController` and use code    `<context:component-scan annotation-config="true" base-package="com.demo.test"/>` and   `<context:annotation-config />` into `ApplicationContaxt.xml` file to scan the base package, this bass package scan use to scan the annotation. you can also use another way where you need to create the bean using java class configuration and create the object for autowire. in java configuration class you need to use `@Configuration` annotation. you can find below sample code for configuration where i am create bean for `modelMapper` classs

```
@Configuration
public class ModelMapperConfig {

@Bean(name = "modelMapper")
public ModelMapper getModelMapper() {
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    return modelMapper;
}

@Bean(name = "modelMapperWithConverter")
public ModelMapper getModelMapperWithConverter() {
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    return modelMapper;
}
```

you can also create bean from xml clas, you need to create bean into `ApplicationContacxt.xml`. you can find sample code below:

```
 <bean id = "advertisementRepo" class = "com.amstech.mayal.demo.test.AdvertisementRepo" />
```